# jQuery unveil - finding the left and right of screen using jQuery

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

I am looking at using a bit of lightweight code which I found which does LazyLoading by switching data-src to src when the item is visible.  Basically a cut down of the full fat LazyLoad.  Code from here:  http://luis-almeida.github.com/unveil/

```
(function( $ ) {

$.fn.unveil = function( threshold ) {
    var $w = $( window ), 
        th = threshold || 0,
        images = this, 
        loaded, 
        inview,
        source;

    this.one( "unveil", function(){
        source = this.getAttribute( "data-src" );
        this.setAttribute( "src", source );
        this.removeAttribute( "data-src" );
    } );

    function unveil() {
        inview = images.filter(function(){
            var $e = $( this ),
                wt = $w.scrollTop(),
                wb = wt + $w.height(),
                et = $e.offset().top,
                eb = et + $e.height();

            return eb >= wt - th && et <= wb + th;
        });

        loaded = inview.trigger( "unveil" );
        images = images.not( loaded );
    }

    $w.scroll( unveil );
    $w.resize( unveil );

    unveil();

    return this;
};

})( jQuery );
```

However, my jQuery knowledge is pretty limited so from what I can tell is that is that the visibility check is based on the vertical position of the scrollTop.

I am trying to use this on a part of my e-commerce store where there are a number of products within a horizontal jQuery Tool Scrollable div.  Since they are within the vertical part of the screen it loads all the images.  I tried to use LazyLoad but couldn't make it work.

Does anyone know how to edit this code so that the function can detect that the images in the div to the right in the overflow (which is hidden) and therefore should not be loaded - ie. is the position of the image to right of a certain point?

Comment: If anyone is interested in doing this - take a look at https://github.com/sebarmeli/JAIL - which works out of the box.  You can simply add $(".scrollable").bind("onSeek", function() {
    $('img.lazy').jail();
  }); to make it check the display after you have scrolled.

Comment: unveil is designed to only work with the window scrolling, not a div scrolling. That is why it only works vertically. If you want someone to write code for you so it works in a div they will likely need incentive or a pre-set up jFiddle to play in that is set up the way you need it to work.